# How to prove each element of the following sequence is a perfect square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies the following formula:

$a_{n+2}=14a_{n+1}-a_n+12$,

and $a_1=1, a_2=1$.

It is easy to check that $a_3=25$ and $a_4=361$.

The question is how to prove each element of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a perfect square?

Comment: The first few square roots are $1$, $1$, $5$, $19$, $71$, $265$, $989$ which (eventually, and apparently) satisfies the recurrence $b_{n+2} = 4b_{n+1} - b_n$.

Comment: Replace $b_1$ with $-1$ and the recurrence is valid from the start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Umberto P. commented, it is sufficient to prove by induction that
$$a_{n+2}=b_n^2\tag1$$
where $b_{n+2}=4b_{n+1}-b_{n}$ with $b_0=1, b_1=5$.

The base case : $a_2=1=b_0^2$ and $a_3=25=b_1^2$

Suppose that $a_{n+2}=b_n^2$ and $a_{n+1}=b_{n-1}^2$.

Then, using that 
$$b_n^2-4b_nb_{n-1}+b_{n-1}^2=6\tag2$$
we get
$$\begin{align}a_{n+3}&=14a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}+12\\&=14b_{n}^2-b_{n-1}^2+12\\&=16b_n^2-8b_nb_{n-1}+b_{n-1}^2-2b_n^2+8b_nb_{n-1}-2b_{n-1}^2+12\\&=(4b_n-b_{n-1})^2-2(b_n^2-4b_nb_{n-1}+b_{n-1}^2-6)\\&=b_{n+1}^2\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

Let us prove $(2)$ by induction.

The base case : $b_1^2-4b_1b_0+b_0^2=25-20+1=6$

Suppose that $b_n^2-4b_nb_{n-1}+b_{n-1}^2=6$. Then,

$$\begin{align}b_{n+1}^2-4b_{n+1}b_{n}+b_{n}^2&=(4b_{n}-b_{n-1})^2-4(4b_{n}-b_{n-1})b_n+b_n^2\\&=16b_{n}^2-8b_{n}b_{n-1}+b_{n-1}^2-16b_n^2+4b_nb_{n-1}+b_n^2\\&=b_n^2-4b_nb_{n-1}+b_{n-1}^2\\&=6\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Comment: This is great! Other proofs that avoid inductions are also very nice

Answer (score 9):

I don't know a simpler way than breaking down the generating function: let $b_n=a_n+1$; then $b_{n+2}$ $= a_{n+2}+1$ $= 14a_{n+1}-a_n+12+1$ $=14(b_{n+1}-1)-(b_n-1)+13$ $= 14b_{n+1}-b_n$, so the recurrence relation for $b_n$ is homogeneous.  The characteristic equation is $x^2-14x+1=0$ with roots $7\pm4\sqrt{3}$, which are themselves the squares of $2\pm\sqrt{3}$; note that $(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})=1$.  This isn't coincidence: if you look at the equation $c_{n+2}=4c_{n+1}-c_n$ (whose characteristic equation $x^2-4x+1=0$ has $2\pm\sqrt{3}$ for its roots) with initial conditions $c_1=-1$, $c_2=1$ you'll find that you have $a_n=c_n^2$.

This works because we have $c_n=x(2+\sqrt{3})^n+y(2-\sqrt{3})^n$, with $x=\frac12(3\sqrt{3}-5)$ and $y=-\frac12(3\sqrt{3}+5)$and so when we square $c_n$ we get a result of the form $x^2(2+\sqrt{3})^{2n}+y^2(2-\sqrt{3})^{2n}+xy\left((2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})\right)^n$ — but $xy$ is $-1$ and the last term in parenthesesis just $1$ for all $n$, so $c_n^2+1$ is of the form $sz^n+t\bar{z}^n$ (where $\bar{z}$ denotes the conjugate with respect to $\sqrt{3}$), and so it satisfies a second-degree homogeneous linear equation with integer coefficients — specifically, the equation for $b_n$.

The key here is that the (conjugate) roots of the equation have norm $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, so the cross term will always be $1$; there's no exponential growth there, so we can offset the square by a constant factor to get another homogeneous linear equation.  The same trick would work for e.g. an equation like $x^2-66x+1=0$ (i.e., $c_{n+2}=66c_{n+1}-c_n$) with conjugate roots $z,\bar{z}=33\pm8\sqrt{17}$ that satisfy $z\bar{z}=1$; with the right initial conditions you'll find exactly the same phenomenon that the solutions of $d_{n+2}=4354d_{n+1}-d_n$ (whose roots are $z^2$ and $\bar{z}^2$) satisfy $d_n=c_n^2-1$.

Answer (score 5):

The scenic route.

This begins with Umberto's comment that $ x_{n+2} - 4 x_{n+1} + x_n = 0, $ so I knew I wanted a 2 by 2 matrix of trace $4$ and determinant $1,$ with preference for one with the two diagonal terms equal, because those serve as automorphism matrices for Pell type quadratic forms. I thought of 
$$
 \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 3 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and began thinking of $x^2 - 3 y^2.$ Looking at the first few items, $1,25,361,$ in each case we get triple a square just by adding $2,$ as in $3,27,363.$ So, $x^2 + 2 = 3 y^2,$ or $x^2 - 3 y^2 = -2.$

Take $x^2 - 3 y^2$ as a quadratic form, and solve for $x^2 - 3 y^2 = -2.$ 
The "automorphism matrix" says that
$$  
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 3 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x_{n} \\
y_{n}
\end{array}
\right), 
$$ 
or, from Cayley Hamilton,
$$ x_{n+2} - 4 x_{n+1} + x_n = 0, $$
$$ y_{n+2} - 4 y_{n+1} + y_n = 0. $$

If we simply multiply out the entries we get
$$  
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1}^2 \\
x_{n+1} y_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1}^2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
4 & 12 & 9 \\
2 & 7 & 6 \\
1 & 4 & 4
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n}^2 \\
x_{n} y_{n} \\
y_{n}^2
\end{array}
\right) 
$$ 
This 3 by 3 matrix is sort of famous, as we have taken a 2 by 2 matrix in the modular group and produced a 3 by 3 image in $SL_3 \mathbb Z;$ the map is an isomorphism. You can find this construction on [page 58 of Zagier](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540106036) or [page 23 of Magnus](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14594714~S1). Actually, Magnus and Zagier use transposes of each other's matrices, can't have everything. With the letters permuted, [page 301 of Cassels](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html).

The coefficient matrix has determinant $1.$ In fact, the characteristic polynomial is $$ \lambda^3 - 15 \lambda^2 + 15 \lambda - 1 = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda^2 - 14 \lambda + 1). $$

The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem says that
$$ x_{n+3}^2 - 15 x_{n+2}^2 + 15 x_{n+1}^2 - x_{n}^2 = 0.  $$

NOW, suppose I have any sequence $z_n$ with
$$ z_{n+3} - 15 z_{n+2} + 15 z_{n+1} - z_{n} = 0,  $$
and I define
$$  w_n = z_{n+2} - 14 z_{n+1} + z_n. $$
THEN
$$  w_{n+1} = z_{n+3} - 14 z_{n+2} + z_{n+1}, $$ AND
$$ w_{n+1} - w_n =  z_{n+3} - 15 z_{n+2} + 15 z_{n+1} - z_{n} = 0,$$
or $w_n$ is constant! Taking $z_n = x_n^2,$ we get
$$  x_{n+2}^2 - 14 x_{n+1}^2 + x_{n}^2 = \mbox{CONSTANT}.  $$
Check with the triple $1,5,19$ beginning $x_n,$ we find
$$  x_{n+2}^2 - 14 x_{n+1}^2 + x_{n}^2 = 12.  $$

It is not difficult to confirm that, given an element of the modular group (our "automorphism matrix")
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta
\end{array}
\right), 
$$
so that $$ \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1, $$ then construct
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha^2 & 2 \alpha \beta & \beta^2 \\
\alpha \gamma & (\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma) & \beta \delta \\
\gamma^2 & 2 \gamma \delta & \delta^2
\end{array}
\right), 
$$
that the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is
$$  \lambda^3 - \left( (\alpha + \delta)^2 - 1 \right) \lambda^2  + \left( (\alpha + \delta)^2 - 1 \right) \lambda - 1 = (\lambda - 1) \left(  \lambda^2 -  \left( (\alpha + \delta)^2 - 2 \right) \lambda + 1  \right)  $$
Part of this is the claim that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M.$ Here is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1:$
$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2 \beta  \\
 \delta - \alpha \\
 - 2 \gamma 
\end{array}
\right), 
$$
with $MX=X,$ and $X$ is nonzero unless $W = \pm I,$ in which case $M=I$ and all eigenvalues become $1.$

Here is page 301 in Cassels. He switches $\beta, \gamma$ in the 3 by 3 matrix, compared with what I typed above.

[image]

Here is a start:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    2   3
    1   2
  Automorphism backwards:  
    2   -3
    -1   2

  2^2 - 3 1^2 = 1

 x^2 - 3 y^2 = -2

Tue Aug 23 11:43:01 PDT 2016

x:  1  y:  1 ratio: 1  SEED   KEEP +- 
x:  5  y:  3 ratio: 1.66667
x:  19  y:  11 ratio: 1.72727
x:  71  y:  41 ratio: 1.73171
x:  265  y:  153 ratio: 1.73203
x:  989  y:  571 ratio: 1.73205
x:  3691  y:  2131 ratio: 1.73205
x:  13775  y:  7953 ratio: 1.73205
x:  51409  y:  29681 ratio: 1.73205
x:  191861  y:  110771 ratio: 1.73205
x:  716035  y:  413403 ratio: 1.73205
x:  2672279  y:  1542841 ratio: 1.73205
x:  9973081  y:  5757961 ratio: 1.73205

Tue Aug 23 11:43:31 PDT 2016

 x^2 - 3 y^2 = -2

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Calculations for showing that the mapping from 2 by 2 matrices to 3 by 3, as in Magnus page 23, is an isomorphism.

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? m = [ a,b; c,d]
%1 = 
[a b]

[c d]

? m3 = [ a^2, 2 * a * b, b^2; a * c, a * d + b * c, b * d; c^2, 2 * c * d, d^2]
%2 = 
[a^2 2*b*a b^2]

[c*a d*a + c*b d*b]

[c^2 2*d*c d^2]

? matdet(m3) - ( matdet(m) )^3
%24 = 0

? n = [ e,f; g,h]
%3 = 
[e f]

[g h]

? n3 = [ e^2, 2 * e * f, f^2; e * g, e * h + f * g, f * h; g^2, 2 * g * h, h^2]
%4 = 
[e^2 2*f*e f^2]

[g*e h*e + g*f h*f]

[g^2 2*h*g h^2]

? m * n
%5 = 
[e*a + g*b f*a + h*b]

[e*c + g*d f*c + h*d]

? 
? 
? m3 * n3
%6 = 
[e^2*a^2 + 2*g*e*b*a + g^2*b^2 2*f*e*a^2 + (2*h*e + 2*g*f)*b*a + 2*h*g*b^2 f^2*a^2 + 2*h*f*b*a + h^2*b^2]

[(e^2*c + g*e*d)*a + (g*e*c + g^2*d)*b (2*f*e*c + (h*e + g*f)*d)*a + ((h*e + g*f)*c + 2*h*g*d)*b (f^2*c + h*f*d)*a + (h*f*c + h^2*d)*b]

[e^2*c^2 + 2*g*e*d*c + g^2*d^2 2*f*e*c^2 + (2*h*e + 2*g*f)*d*c + 2*h*g*d^2 f^2*c^2 + 2*h*f*d*c + h^2*d^2]

? t = m * n
%7 = 
[e*a + g*b f*a + h*b]

[e*c + g*d f*c + h*d]

? t[1,1]
%8 = e*a + g*b
? t[1,2]
%9 = f*a + h*b
? t[2,1]
%10 = e*c + g*d
? t[2,2]
%11 = f*c + h*d
? 
? u = m3 * n3
%12 = 
[e^2*a^2 + 2*g*e*b*a + g^2*b^2 2*f*e*a^2 + (2*h*e + 2*g*f)*b*a + 2*h*g*b^2 f^2*a^2 + 2*h*f*b*a + h^2*b^2]

[(e^2*c + g*e*d)*a + (g*e*c + g^2*d)*b (2*f*e*c + (h*e + g*f)*d)*a + ((h*e + g*f)*c + 2*h*g*d)*b (f^2*c + h*f*d)*a + (h*f*c + h^2*d)*b]

[e^2*c^2 + 2*g*e*d*c + g^2*d^2 2*f*e*c^2 + (2*h*e + 2*g*f)*d*c + 2*h*g*d^2 f^2*c^2 + 2*h*f*d*c + h^2*d^2]

? u[1,1]
%13 = e^2*a^2 + 2*g*e*b*a + g^2*b^2
? u[1,2]
%14 = 2*f*e*a^2 + (2*h*e + 2*g*f)*b*a + 2*h*g*b^2
? u[1,2] - 2 * t[1,1] * t[1,2]
%15 = 0
? u[1,1] - t[1,1] * t[1,1]
%16 = 0
? u[1,3] - t[1,2] * t[1,2]
%17 = 0
? u[2,1] - t[1,1] * t[2,1]
%18 = 0
? u[2,2] - t[1,1] * t[2,2] - t[1,2] * t[2,1]
%19 = 0
? u[2,3] - t[1,2] * t[2,2]
%20 = 0
? u[3,1] - t[2,1] * t[2,1]
%21 = 0
? u[3,2] - 2 * t[2,1] * t[2,2]
%22 = 0
? u[3,3] -  t[2,2] * t[2,2]
%23 = 0
?
```

Answer (score 0):

The above proofs are elegant. The following is what I was thinking:

Like what Steven did, we can use generation functions and write out $$a_n = c(2+\sqrt{3})^{2n} + d(2-\sqrt{3})^{2n} - 1$$ for some constants $c$ and $d$. Note that $c>0$ since $a_n$ increases as $n$ increases. If $d>0$, then $a_n = (\sqrt{c}((2+\sqrt{3})^n - \sqrt{d}(2-\sqrt{3})^n)^2 + (2\sqrt{cd} - 1 )$, and we want to show $ 2\sqrt{cd} - 1=0$, or $cd=1/4$.

Write $\sigma = (2+\sqrt{3})$,  from $a_1=a_2$ we have $c\sigma^2 + d\sigma^{-2} = c\sigma^4 + d\sigma^{-4}$, which simplifies to $d=c\sigma^6$; then $d>c>0$.  We also have $2=a_1+1= c\sigma^2 + d\sigma^{-2} = c\sigma^2(1+\sigma^2) = c\sigma^2*4\sigma$, so $c\sigma^3= 1/2$, which yields $2\sqrt{cd} - 1= 2c\sigma^3-1= 0$. We then have $a_n=b_n^2$, where $b_n=\sqrt{c}(2+\sqrt{3})^n - \sqrt{d}(2-\sqrt{3})^n$. The sequence $\{b_n\}$ are integers since $b_1=b_2=1$ and $b_{n+2} = 4b_{n+1}-b_n$.